# Using "unique" filter, Elasticsearch analyzes tokens incorrectly

Tags: elasticsearch, token, elasticsearch-query

I've been trying to use the **unique ** token filter in my analyzer, but it continue to use duplicate tokens while scoring.

## **Analyzer:**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "tnved_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",    
                        "stemmer",
                        "unique"
                    ]
                }
            }           
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "NAME": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "tnved_analyzer"
            },
            "CODE": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## **Request:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "NAME": "Pork fresh or chilled"
    }
  }
}
```

## **Responce:**

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
      **  "max_score": 14.432465,**
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "tnved14_code",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1oajS4cBEkrkvkWeGRXx",
                "_score": 14.432465,
                "_source": {
                    "CODE": "0203",
                    "NAME": **"Pork fresh or chilled"**
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Score for complete coincidence = **14.432465**
I expect to get the same score for request **"Pork fresh or chilled Pork fresh or chilled"** (because here tokens will be the same as in request above **"Pork fresh or chilled"**:

- pork
- fresh
- or
- chilled

BUT I get score twice higher: 28.864931

I need get 14.432465.
What's wrong?

I need get 14.432465.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your text with the analyze API to understand how it's tokenized. And you can understand how it's scored.

```
GET index_name/_analyze
{
  "text": "Pork fresh or chilled",
  "analyzer": "tnved_analyzer"
}
```

Also, the [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) will help you to understand how the score calculated.

Comment: You're welcome, what did you changed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few factors that define the score of the document:

- TF (term frequency) – The more a term appears in a single field, the more relevant it is.
- IDF (inverse document frequency) – The more documents that have the search term, the less relevant it is.
- Field Length – Smaller fields are naturally more relevant than longer fields.

I recommend reading this [post](https://www.compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/)